# how to scroll to a specific id of home page from a navigation button from different page?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, routes, navigation

if i click any navigation button from different page except home page I want to load home page first and then scroll to the corresponding id mention in navlink. here is my code

```
      <Col sm={5}>
        <Nav className="me-auto p-3 ">
          <Nav.Link href="./#home" className="navlink">
            Home
          </Nav.Link>
          <Nav.Link href="./#About" className="navlink">
            About
          </Nav.Link>
          <Nav.Link href="./#Projects" className="navlink">
            Projects
          </Nav.Link>
          <Nav.Link href="./#Contact" className="navlink">
            Contact
          </Nav.Link>
        </Nav>
      </Col>re
```

Comment: try removing ` ./` from `./#id`

Answer (score 0):

file1.html:

```
...
<p id="scroll"></p>
...
```

file2.html:

```
<a href="/absolute/path/to/file1.html#scroll">Scroll</a>
or
<a href="relative/path/to/file1.html#scroll">Scroll</a>
```

Comment: Actually i am using react in this project. so how can I load a component in the place of file1.html.